# Require certain checkin comment text in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, tfs, tfvc

Is there a way to require certain text in the checkin comment in Visual Studio (currently on VS '15), for certain projects? For source control right now we are using TFVC.

So if I have project SampleProject, and someone makes a change, I would like their checkin comment to say

> This text is whatever I want to say about my checkin.
>
> **Required Text: Bar**

The required text could be one of several different texts (Bar, Foo, etc).

What I am trying to accomplish is a way to automate the versioning of my projects that build in Jenkins. Right now my versioning is set in Jenkins, with the form x.y.z.Jenkins_Build_Id, which overwrites values in the AssemblyInfo.cs. And if I want to increment x/y/z I have to do that by hand, as I haven't found a solution for incrementing those values in an automated way.

But I would like to be able to say *if the changesets that caused the build contain 'Major version' then increment x, 'Minor Version' then increment y, 'Patch' then increment z*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS provides a default check-in policy named **Changeset comments policy**, this policy will require users to provide check-in comments. But there is no rule to require comments that include a specific text.

So you can create your own custom check-in policy to do what you're looking for. Check out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) for an example of how to do this, as well as [this blog](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html).

Please notice, if your OS is 64-bit, you must add the checkin policy under the **Wow6432Node** instead of the path stated on MSDN:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies
```